# Enforce distinctness of datatypes

Tags: isabelle

I have defined the following datatype in Isabelle

```
datatype bc_t =  B | C
```

and don't see how to prove the following basic lemma

```
lemma "∀ x::bc_t . (x=B ⟶ x≠C)"
```

Under the assumption `B≠C` the proof goes through:

```
lemma "⟦B≠C; x=B⟧ ⟹ x≠C"
by metis
```

Is there a way to prove the Lemma without an explicit assumption that `B` and `C` are distinct?

**Update:** As Manuel Eberl suggested in the comment to the answer, the problem was caused by an erroneous simplification rule (lemma with a `[simp]` attribute, omitted here) which made the simplification process loop and thus ignore the automatically generated simplification rules `B≠C`, `C≠B` (found in `bs_t.simps`, as pointed out by Chris in his answer). As in the answer by gc44, `simp` suffices to prove the lemma in a normal situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let the auto tools give you a big head start. It will take me much more work to tell you the multiple ways to get feedback from the auto tools than it took me to prove the theorem.

```
datatype bc_t =  B | C

lemma "∀ x::bc_t . (x = B ⟶ x ~= C)"
try0
using[[simp_trace]] 
using [[simp_trace_depth_limit=100]]
apply(simp)
done

lemma "∀ x::bc_t . (x = B ⟶ x ~= C)"
sledgehammer
by (metis bc_t.distinct(1))
```

I used `try0` because I had unchecked `Auto Methods` in "Plugin Options / Isabelle / General". Many times in the options I have all the auto tools boxes checked other than Sledgehammer.

You can use `sledgehammer` as I show there or you can use it in the Sledgehammer panel of the PIDE. With `simp_trace`, when you put your cursor on the line with `apply(simp)`, you can learn how the `simp` method proved it, which will be based on substitution rules.

**Update 140108_1305**

The auto tools are important for helping us work fast, but it's also important to sometimes understand the basic logic of the proof. This is where `simp_trace` and other attributes of the `simp` method can be useful. Read `tutorial.pdf`, `prog-prove.pdf` and `isar-ref.pdf` for some details and lessons on using `simp`.

Three such attributes for controlling the `simp` method are `add`, `del`, and `only`.

In your example, I want to use the `simp_trace`, along with `only`, to make it explicit what rules are being used, to maybe help me understand the logic.

The `metis` proof by Sledgehammer makes it appear that `simp` may only be using a few rules. I look at the `simp` trace and let `simp` only use rules that I can cut and paste from the control panel. I count 4 named rules, and this is not going to actually turn out to be something that's worth doing, though I had to find that out.

[**Update** 140101_0745: Trying not to over analyze the situation, I ended up using `del` because my grand scheme of using `only` wasn't working out. With `simp only` in the place of `simp del` below, the `apply` method fails with an error, which means it can't simplify the goal with only those four rules. This will not be the case with `auto simp only` instead of `simp only`. The `auto` method isn't limited in the way `simp` is, and it may do many things it won't tell you about, such as calling `blast`.]

```
lemma "∀ x::bc_t . (x = B ⟶ x ~= C)"    
using[[simp_trace]] 
using [[simp_trace_depth_limit=100]]
apply(simp del: 
    bc_t.distinct(1)
    simp_thms(8)
    simp_thms(17)
    simp_thms(35)
    ) 
oops
```

Well, now when I look at the newest `simp` trace, there are bunch more `simp` rules. The simplifier has more than 1 stone to kill the bird, so I give up.

One thing to remember is that you can use `simp` with methods like `auto` and `fastforce`, like `apply(auto simp add: stufferThm)`. With `auto` in particular, if the `simp` rules are not enough to prove a theorem, it may resort to using `blast`, which won't show up in the `simp` trace. This is important to know when using `only`, so you're not under the impressions that the `simp` rules are all that's needed for a proof that's found by `auto`.

Here I make some comments about your comment below.

If `simp` stays purple very long, it's having to do a massive number of simplifications, or it's in a non-terminating loop, as Eberl mentions. Either is bad. I don't consider a 40 second `simp` proof a good proof.

Basically, it's very easy to get `simp` in a loop, or any of the other methods that call `simp`, especially if you're defining your own `simp` rules. The `simp` method is easy when it works. When it doesn't, you may have to work for your logic.

Use `try0`, and when no proof is found, it will give you a list of automatic proof methods to experiment with, like `force`, `fastforce`, `auto`, etc. If `simp` is looping with `auto`, you might try it with `fastforce`. Experimenting counts for a lot.

One other important thing to remember is to unfold definitions that aren't `simp` rules. Sledgehammer can sometimes find definitions, but sometimes the most simple of theorems can't be proved because a definition hasn't been unfolded.

[**Update** 140109_0750: Making generalizations is always risky. Unfolding a definition will many times prevent Sledgehammer from finding a proof. Sledgehammer works well by matching up high-level theorems, so a hopelessly expanded formula will many times doom it to failure. Even a hugely expanded formula can cause other auto methods to not be able to find a proof. However, for things of a computational nature based on equations, expanding definitions can allow `simp` to completely reduce a huge, complicated expression. You have to know when to hold them, and when to unfold them. The great thing is it's easy to try lots of things reasonably fast.]

```
definition stuffTrue :: "bool" where
  "stuffTrue = True"

theorem "stuffTrue"
  apply(unfold stuffTrue_def)
  by(simp)
```

It's not the question that's trivial. Simple things aren't necessarily easy to prove. What's trivial is the typing that's required once you learn how to use the auto tools.

Comment: I get bragging rights for having answered the 100th question tagged "Isabelle". These type of bragging is important because when it comes to ego-stroking, the Isabelle crowd is brutal. They don't give you no ego-stroking freebies.

Comment: Please disregard that last comment, except within the context of tech-trash-talking nonsense.

Comment: Thanks! Very sorry for a trivial question. When I copied your answer in a new .thy file it worked. However in my longer file where I'm experimenting neither "simp" nor "auto" work for this lemma ("try0 apply (simp)" is highlighted purple in jEdit with no specific error message). Perhaps I am having some name clash, but don't see it yet. Thanks again!

Comment: If I recall correctly, purple highlighting means that the simplifier loops. Are you using any custom simp rules that could cause this? Again, tracing the simplifier can help.

Comment: Manuel, yes that turned out to be the cause! I had a lemma marked with `[simp]` that apparently made the simplifier loop. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing answer, gc44! Thanks so much for taking the time and posting all those hints. My Isabelle question was really lucky to become your 100th :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `datatype` a bunch of simplification rules will be derived automatically (under the name `<datatype-name>.simps`) and added to the simplifier. In your example it would be

```
datatype bc_t =  B | C
thm bc_t.simps

B ≠ C
C ≠ B
(case B of B ⇒ ?f1.0 | C ⇒ ?f2.0) = ?f1.0
(case C of B ⇒ ?f1.0 | C ⇒ ?f2.0) = ?f2.0
bc_t_rec ?f1.0 ?f2.0 B = ?f1.0
bc_t_rec ?f1.0 ?f2.0 C = ?f2.
```

which includes the fact the `B` and `C` are different. (A subset of those facts, only talking about distinctness, is available via the name `bc_t.distinct`.)

With those simplification rules in place it is possible to solve your lemma `by simp`.

Comment: One thing leads to another. `datatype` being a data type, it wasn't obvious for me to say, "Let me use the feedback in the output panel about rules to track down exactly what `simp` rules where automatically created." So now, the info I see when my cursor is at `datatype bc_t = B | c` actually has some meaning to me. I'm slowly coming to grips with the `Rep` representative and `Abs` abstraction functions that get automatically created by lots of Isar commands. I see a `bc_t_rep_set`. I suppose this wouldn't be a place for a mini-lesson from you about `Abs` or `Rep`. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for a very useful hint, Chris!